# Can I use Materialize CSS with Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, material-design, materialize

I want to use Materialize CSS library along with Ionic app. Can I use it? Will it have any performance issues?

Is there any other library so that I can give a 'Material Design' feel to my app

Comment: [check here](http://ionicmaterial.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Materializecss or Google Material Design. Either will work fine with Ionic. Both have plenty of documentation. Assuming you're using bower -

1. For Google MDL

   bower install material-design-lite --save

then just include the css and js in your index.html file

```
<link href="lib/material-design-lite/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/material-design-lite/material.min.js"></script>
```

2. For Materializecss

   bower install materialize

then include the basic files in your index.html file.

```
<link href="lib/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/materialize/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

You may have to change the directories to the correct path of your bower installs.

Documentation on both for referring to components, css, javascript.

1. Google MDL = https://getmdl.io/components/index.html
2. Materializecss = http://materializecss.com/